# Access subform datasheet using VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba, datasheet

I currently have a subform which is loaded as a datasheet. So when I click the form, it will display current records (shown below but blurred)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XbdLq.jpg

What I want to do is somehow, in VBA, access the form and it's datasheet to manipulate the cell data. I.e. thisform.sheet.cell(1,1) = somevalue

So far I've managed to get access to the form object with Form!Name

Comment: Just how do you want to "manipulate the cell data"? Certain fields based on some decision, or all rows or columns? What is supposed to trigger the change? Will you double-click a field, or other?

Comment: THe change will be triggered by a button press:

So, once the button is clicked, a function will run to change some of these cells

Comment: For clarity, since this is an Access datasheet and not Excel, I believe when you say 'cells', you really mean fields. I assume the data shown in those fields originated in one of your tables, which is used as a recordsource for that form?  You would need to either add VBA code to perform some type of row-by-row update based on whatever logic you use, or you would need to run an 'update' query to update based on some criteria. Finally, you would need to refresh the data (i.e. 'requery'). Is this close to what you want to happen?

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes, the recordsource of the access form is fed by the data from the tables. But I want to make it so that when the user creates a new record (which will mean the recordsource is blank) the fields will be prepopulated already with some rows of data.

I know how to get access to a form's recordsource, so my next question would be how do I get access to each row in the recordsource / manipulate these rows?

Comment: I believe your subform is bound to a recordset and possibly linked to some related record in the main form? And when the user 'creates' a new record on the main form, by default there will be no 'new' or  'related' records in the subform?  And you want to automatically add a few records for the subform that will be related? If all these assumptions are true, then in the main form, add VBA code to the 'Form After Insert' event to add related rows to the table that is used for the subform. Either use SQL 'Insert Into' or VBA '.AddNew'. Is this what you want?

Comment: Just as an aside, as you ask about cells, is this a linked Excel sheet (as opposed to data from an Access table, including an imported Excel sheet)? If it's linked to a live Excel file, you can't update it from Access - you could in versions previous to 2007 but it was then removed due to a legal conflict.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a recordset object, and iterate over the object.

```
Dim acRS1 as Recordset
```

You will then need to assign the recordset to the actual table that you want

```
Set acRS1 = db.OpenRecordset("sometablethatIwanttoupdate",dbOpenDynaset)
```

You will then need to update the recordset in the manner that you need, which you do not include in your original question.

I will update with the appropriate code when you clarify the exact changes to be made to the recordset (do we want to update a record or add a new record?)